# Data update without Page refresh after Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, session

Kindly pardon me if i look silly mates.

My issue is , i have a profile page which on update and submit changes the data in db. To refresh the data then, i use select query after that. Then i save it in the current session. still the changes happens only in the page where the update and select query presents . I have some pages which is been included like top bar, left nav . which changes only if i refresh the page . My code is as follows

```
<?php

     if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $name_t = $_POST['name'];
        $email_t = $_POST['email'];
        $pass_t = $_POST['password'];
        $contact_t = $_POST['contact'];
        $address_t = $_POST['address'];
        $dob_t = $_POST['dob'];
        $religion_t = $_POST['religion'];
        $pic_t = ($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
        $sql = "
UPDATE teacher 
   SET t_name = '$name_t'
      , t_email = '$email_t'
      , t_password = '$pass_t'
      , t_phone = '$contact_t'
      , t_address = '$address_t'
      , t_dob = '$dob_t'
      , t_religion = '$religion_t' 
 where teacher_id='$update_id' 
";
        $retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);        
        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
      if (!empty($_FILES['imagefile']['name'])) {
      $sql = "UPDATE teacher SET t_photo = '$pic_t' where teacher_id='$update_id' ";
      $retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);
      $info = pathinfo($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
      $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
        $target = 'img/upload/'.$pic_t;
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], $target);
    }
     }  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher where teacher_id='$update_id' ",$link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row['t_name'];
    $email = $row['t_email'];
    $password = $row['t_password'];
    $contact = $row['t_phone'];
    $address = $row['t_address'];
    $dob = $row['t_dob'];
    $religion = $row['t_religion'];
    $img = WEB_URL . 'img/upload/'.$row['t_photo'];
    $_SESSION['objLogin'] = $row;
}
 mysql_close($link);
 ?>
```

Kindly help me in updating the included page too without refresh . Because for instance there is the username displayed at top bar .

Comment: in top bar value you use session data

Comment: @AslamPatel That's what i used mate . Session is properly updated . the issue is only on page reload or refresh the change takes place mate .

Comment: Note that about 100 years ago we stopped using PHP's mysql_ API, and everything bad with which it was associated

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for intimating me mate , i am new to php and learning. Do you mean to avoid mysql and use mysqli mate ? if so i will follow that mate

Comment: Yes. Or PDO, and, crucially, prepared statements.